# Adobe Air relative performance

Tags: .net, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, air

How do Adobe Air applications (written in flash or flex) perform in relation to other technologies such as .Net?

By 'perform' I mean:

1. Graphics/rendering (drawing shapes to on a canvas for example)
2. Loop/mathematical performance (e.g. an eratosthenes sieve)

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are so many factors to performance; it is impossible to answer this concretely.  I voted to close.

Comment: Admittedly there are open-ended interpretations of my topic, I am really looking for specific answers to my two questions.

Comment: you'll need a specific question to get a specific answer.  "How is performance of.." is not a question definitively answerable.  The specs of the client, for example, could greatly affect performance.

Comment: You might want to wait for some data for AIR 3. Adobe has been very "passionate" about some of the new features, namely stage3d and "Native extensions". See http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air3_whatsnew.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, Flash/Flex almost always wins in the graphics rendering department except for a few different places since hardware acceleration is still in its infancy for Flash.  And since Flash is frame based, it normally provides smoother animations and transitions.

.NET will almost always win the computational side since it has threading and faster processing power.  It really depends what you're trying to do.  Flash/Flex was never really meant to be used as a computational powerhouse since that isn't what it was designed for.  It was made to be a UX centric tool to help users.  With that said though, if you really need crazy performance, you can always offload it to a native process (separate .NET app that just calculates stuff) which in it's own way is kind of like having a thread since it's asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this - http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/05/09/flash-vs-silverlight-what-suits-your-needs-best/

It has a great detail of the comparison of the two, with other references as well.

It would essentially depend on what you are building, to choose between the two.

Comment: This article answers part 1 very well.

Comment: Actually, that article was extremely biased and lacking in information on both sides.